# Busqueda en laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

Al querer mostrar los registros de una tabla y su tabla relacionada, en este caso me gustaría mostrar los nombres y productos, hice mi relación pero hasta ahí llegue, este es mi código:

Esto esta dentro del modelo que tiene la tabla relacionada

```
public function producto(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Producto','id','id_productos');
    }
```

y en la parte de mi controller solo pude llegar a esto:

```
public function mostrarList(Request $request){
        try{
         $dataTienda = Tienda::where('name','LIKE','%'.$request->name.'%')->get();
           return view('/webList')->with(array(
                'allTienda' => $dataTienda
            ));
        }catch (\Exception $e){
            dd($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: El segundo método with() con que método va a trabajar? Por qué lo estás mandando sin ese argumento

Comment: disculpa, estaba intentando ahí poder relacionarlo, ya lo pude editar

Comment: No me queda muy claro qué es lo que hay que resolver aquí, ¿podrías agregar una pregunta o párrafo donde se explique puntualmente lo que no funciona o lo que se desea hacer?

Comment: Quisiera poder mostrar la busqueda de un registro, este registro esta relacionado a otra tabla y quisiera mostrar juntos, el registro y la tabla con la que esta relacionada